# Is it possible to change workspace in Talend Open Studio for Data Quality?

Tags: talend, data-quality

Unlike Talend Open Studio (TOS) for Data Integration, **TOS for Data Quality** neither start with a splash screen with project and workspace choices nor permits to change the working project in the Studio. :(

I would like at least to change the workspace location, not to use the default one which is under the installation folder !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not possible unless in commercial editions.

See : https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDQ-7728